# Combining pandas "data frame.style" objects and outputting to html

Tags: python-3.x, html-table, pandas-styles

I would like to combine pandas `df.style` objects that use the following methods - `df.style.background_gradient` and `df.style.bar` and export the result to html.

I'm successful when I have separate objects. Here is an example data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(15).reshape(5, 3))
```

I can then pass this to the different style methods:

```
# Use method "background_gradient"
styled_df_a = df.style.background_gradient(subset=[0, 1], 
                                       low=0, high=0.5, 
                                       cmap="YlGnBu")

# Use method "bar"
styled_df_b = df.style.bar(subset=[2], align='mid', 
                       color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
```

I subsequently export each of the styled tables to html:

```
# Export styled table a to html
html = styled_df_a.render()
with open("df_a.html","w") as fp:
fp.write(html)

# Export styled table b to html
html = styled_df_b.render()
with open("df_b.html","w") as fp:
fp.write(html)
```

I therefore have 2 html rendered styled tables. However, I would like to combine the 2 methods into 1 html styled table, such that columns 1-2 have the `background_gradient` styling and column 3 has the `bar` styling.

I tried this:

```
styled_df_c = styled_df_a.style.bar(subset=[2], align='mid', 
                                color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
```

This doesn't work due to the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'style'
```

Is there a way to do this through some other means? I did try experimenting with the `style.apply` method of pandas but got a similar error as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution based on info here: [mode.com/example-gallery/python_dataframe_styling](https://mode.com/example-gallery/python_dataframe_styling)

Rather than trying to coerce a styled object with more styling methods, you can simply pass multiple style methods to the same data frame simultaneously. Please see below:

```
# example data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(15).reshape(5, 3))

# pass multiple style methods to same  data frame
styled_df = (df.style
             .background_gradient(subset=[0, 1], # background_gradient method
                                  low=0, high=0.5,
                                  cmap="YlGnBu")
             .bar(subset=[2], align='mid',       # bar method
                  color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d']))

# Export "styled_df" to html
html = styled_df.hide_index().render()
with open("html_c.html","w") as fp:
   fp.write(html)
```

Comment: what python version are you using, because i still get this error: AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'hide_index'

Comment: Hi Sam! Sorry for late response. I haven't been on stack for a while. I've been working on a styled dataframe recently (pyhton v3.7.4) and the above syntax still works ok to hide index when exporting to html.

Comment: i gave up and now using beautifulSoup, its easier for me :)